# IS this class Many part of memory Leak

Tags: iphone

I am much confuse about my class.

Specially about Memory Management.

Please Guide me about NSString Concept at here.

My Class is.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface itinerary_detail : NSObject {
    NSString *itinerary_title;
    NSString *itinerary_creator;
    NSString *itinerary_identifiere;

    NSString *itinerary_created;
    NSString *itinerary_modified;    
}
@property (retain) NSString *itinerary_title;
@property (retain) NSString *itinerary_creator;
@property (retain) NSString *itinerary_identifiere;
@property (retain) NSString *itinerary_created;
@property (retain) NSString *itinerary_modified;

-(void) itinerary_initialization;
-(void) itinerary_title:(NSString *) xml_value;
-(void) itinerary_creator:(NSString *) xml_value;
-(void) itinerary_identifiere:(NSString *) xml_value;
-(void) itinerary_created:(NSString *) xml_value;
-(void) itinerary_modified:(NSString *) xml_value;
@end
```

and My .m class is

```
#import "itinerary_detail.h"
@implementation itinerary_detail
@synthesize itinerary_title,itinerary_creator,itinerary_identifiere,itinerary_created,itinerary_modified;
-(void) itinerary_initialization
{
    itinerary_title=@"null";
    itinerary_creator=@"null";
    itinerary_identifiere=@"null";
    itinerary_created=@"null";
    itinerary_modified=@"null";
}

-(void) itinerary_title:(NSString *) xml_value
{
    itinerary_title=xml_value; 
}
-(void) itinerary_creator:(NSString *) xml_value
{
    itinerary_creator=xml_value; 
}
-(void) itinerary_identifiere:(NSString *) xml_value
{
    itinerary_identifiere=xml_value;
}
-(void) itinerary_created:(NSString *) xml_value
{
    itinerary_created=xml_value;
}
-(void) itinerary_modified:(NSString *) xml_value
{
    itinerary_modified=xml_value;
}
-(void) dealloc
{
    [itinerary_title release];
    [itinerary_creator release];
    [itinerary_identifiere release];
    [itinerary_created release];
    [itinerary_modified release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

My question about.

1- Is this type Deceleration of NSString in this class of Memory Leak Issue. If Yes Please How i Will change this.

2- I am Using This class into Other class
Like that

```
itinerary_detail *check=[[itinerary_detail alloc] init];
[check itinerary_initialization];
[check release];
```

my question is this right way . or this is also a Memory Leak Issue.

Please Guide Me How to Deceleration Of this class and How to handle all memory Leak Issues.

Please Help Me

Comment: Hi Mukesh, please learn to properly format the question. For now I'll edit them so that you can see how it's done!

Comment: Can you fix the grammar a bit as well? It's hard to decelerate when you mean to declare.

Answer (score 0):

The problem come from the fact that you don't use the property but directly access the member variable.  replace `itinerary_title=xml_value`by `self.itinerary_title=xml_value`

btw, string properties are usually (copy) and not (retain) and why do you create all those methods while the synthesize will do it for you.

remove the methods from the .h file and from the .m file and set the property as

```
@property (copy) NSString* myString;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code shows that you need to get the basics of Cocoa and Objective-C right, before writing an actual program. Read [Cocoa Fundamentals](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html), [OOP with Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/OOP_ObjC/Introduction/Introduction.html), etc. Resist the urge to start writing programs right now; the time you'll spend to learn the basics will greatly reduce your headache later.

Your code should look like:

```
@interface ItineraryDetail : NSObject {
    NSString *itineraryTitle; 
    ...
}
@property (retain) NSString *itineraryTitle;
@end
```

and

```
@implementation ItineraryDetail
@synthesize itineraryTitle, ... ;

-(id)init{
     self=[super init];
     if(self){
         itineraryTitle=nil;
     }
     return self;
}
-(void) dealloc
{
    [itineraryTitle release];
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

and

```
ItineraryDetail *check=[[ItineraryDetail alloc] init];
  ... use it ...
[check release];
```

A few points:

1. In Objective-C, you don't usually `name_like_this`. You `NameLikeThis`. This is not an absolute rule, but it's customary, and you should follow it in general.
2. You don't write a method like `...Initialize`  separately. Rather, it's implemented using `init`, with `[super init]` inside it.
3. When you synthesize a property named `foo` via `@synthesize foo`, the setter `setFoo:` and the getter `foo:` are automatically generated, so you don't have to provide them manually. And you mistakenly used the name `foo:` for the setter! That will totally confuse the system.
4. The nil value for `NSString` (or any object in Objective-C in general) is not `@"null"` but just `nil`. And the ivars are set to `nil` automatically by the system, so you don't really do that in the initialization method.

Comment: You must return from `init`, and check the result of `-[super init]` before continuing.

Comment: Dear friends,Thanks For help Me, sorry for all that my English. and again thank you all friends

Comment: Friends My One question is again,